# How can I use php to verify that the user has visited adf.ly

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm helping a friend code his websites and he has a button that when people click it, it redirects to an "add" site and then redirects back to his site once the user has clicked "skip add". But he wants the button to change when the user comes back. I was wondering if there was a way to know if the user came from the add site and send the info using PHP so the button can change to "submit"? 
Or if there is a more efficient way please tell me! I'm relatively new to this type of stuff.

Comment: the add site will have to add someting to the url it sends the visitor back to

Comment: if the “add site” is not controlled by you, you can use global var `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` (working not at 100% of cases). If the site is controlled by you, better follow Dagon comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you. I haven't tested it but it should work.

```
<?php 

$adfly = "http://adflylink .com"; // Replace with your adfly link
$link = "http://mysite .com"; // Replace with your site link

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $adfly) {
    header("Location: ".$link);
} 
else {
    header("Location: ".$adfly);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if adfly has and API, but maybe you ca know if he comes from adf.ly by the Referer. This can help you.

```
session_start();

if(!isset( $_SESSION["origReferer"])){
    if($_SESSION["origReferer"]){
        $_SESSION["origReferer"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    }else{
        $_SESSION["origReferer"] = true;
    }
}
```

`$_SESSION["origReferer"]` always is going to have the page where the user come from (adf.ly, google.com, facebook.com or what ever) if he comes from another site or `true` if access directly to your web.

Comment: So I replace `origReferer` by the address of the ad and what to I replace `HTTP_REFERER` with?

Comment: You don't replace `origReferer` (except for changing the name). If you want to know the page the user come from you just do something like `echo $_SESSION["origReferer"]` or what you want to do. If you want to know if the user come from the ad URL do something like `if($_SESSION['origReferer']==$myAdURL) echo 'Yes';`. Keep in mind I'm using SESSION so, is going to be the data every time the user refresh. If you only want to check the first time the trick is diferent. Tell me if is like this. Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php) to learn more.

Comment: No problem bro. If help consider to mark the answaer as the solution. =)